# Displaying images without antialiasing in pyglet

Tags: python, image, antialiasing, pyglet

When I display an image (*say a bitmap*) using pyglet (*by putting the image in a sprite and then drawing the sprite*), it seems to me that the image is automatically antialiased. At least when I enlarge it (say by a scale factor of 2), the result is displayed antialiased. (*Note that a sprite can be very easily scaled by modifying the* `pyglet.sprite.Sprite.scale` *property.*) You see, the behaviour I want is for it to display the enlarged image honestly, without antialiasing. This should be possible if the scale factor is a positive integer right? So for example, when I enlarge the original image by 2, I want the enlarged image to be displayed as if each pixel is now 4 pixels big, but **without antialiasing**. How do I do that?